# How to add sub-headers to the pandas Dataframe in the loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the empty data frame, with the header of the Data frame indicating the groups. Example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['group1', 'group2', 'group3', 'group4', 'group5', 'group6'])
```

Now, I want add the sub-headers to each empty column in loop, because the original data frame is long. I have tried the code given below,

```
for ii in range(len(df.columns)):
    df.columns[ii] = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[ii],['condition_1','condition_2']])
```

The error I am getting is 'Index does not support mutable operations'.
The expected output is,

| group1 |  | group2 |  | group3 |  | group4 |  | group5 |  | group6 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| condition_1 | condition_2 | condition_1 | condition_2 | condition_1 | condition_2 | condition_1 | condition_2 | condition_1 | condition_2 | condition_1 | condition_2 |

How can I add the sub-headers (condition_1 and condition_2) to the to the pandas Data frame in the loop in python?

Thank you.

Comment: you want to have `condition1` and `condition2` for every `group1`  to `group6` right? you double the columns from 6 to 12 columns with that IIUC.

Comment: I don't really understand your objective, can you post the `output`. I think it is easier for everyone to figure out

Comment: Do you want `pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, ['condition_1','condition_2']]))`?

Comment: @Vedant why do you need a loop? This is already using all the columns! Try it

Answer (score 1):

```py
groups = [f"group{i+1}" for i in range(6)]
conditions = [f"condition{i+1}" for i in range(2)]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([groups, conditions]))
```